# Electron-React. How to get local relative file

Tags: reactjs, electron

I am developing a subproject for electron-react, in general, this is not the essence of the problem; when assembling the project, it does not see pictures. How to put a link to a local file located in the app.asar archive in the

```
 <img src = {...} alt = {...} />
```

tag.
Or how best to do it in your opinion

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have assets folder inside src dir

```
import Image1 from "../../assets/image1"
```

then in img tag

```
<img alt="" src={Image1} />
```

alternative way if you use cra and your assets folder in your public folder

```
<img alt="" src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/image1`}
```